# How can I convert control characters to HTML entities?

Tags: xml, perl, character-encoding

I am reading a text file and putting its content within a tag in an xml output file. The problem I am facing is that the input text file contains some control characters like `<96>` or `<92>` which cause my script to output invalid xml.

How can I convert these control characters to corresponding numerical HTML entities so that there is no data loss and the resulting file is valid as well?

I have tried:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/\x96/\&\#150\;/g; s/\x92/\&\#146\;/g;' out_xml
```

But I would like to convert *any* control characters to HTML entities.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: perl -p -i -e 's/\x96/\&\#150\;/g;  s/\x92/\&\#146\;/g;' out_xml but want to do it for any such control characters

Comment: Edited that into your question.

Comment: Use of such control characters is discouraged in the XML 1.0 specification, and if you use the nominally correct references like `&#150;`, they will in fact be interpreted by web browsers as denoting certain printable characters like the en dash “–”. So it’s better to convert them e.g. to special tags, say `<ctl code="96" />` (depending on the intended use of the resulting XML file of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTML::Entities](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aEntities) does what you want:

```
$ perl -MHTML::Entities -le 'print encode_entities("\x96\x92")'
&#150;&#146;
```

Comment: Thanks creaktive, it helped me to achieve me what I was looking for.